# how to use graphics sdl with QEMU

Tags: gtk, sdl, qemu

I would like to start a VM with the sdl graphics option but I always get the error message

`error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2022-12-22T20:37:42.896670Z qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.`

I can't make it works either with gtk, as I get while I create the VM with wirsh

`error: unsupported configuration: unknown graphics device type 'gtk'`

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04

I did install following packages:

`sudo apt install  virt-manager spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper spice-vdagent spice-webdavd spice-client-gtk libpixman-1-dev libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg8-dev libgif-dev ninja-build qemu qemu-kvm virt-viewer libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virtinst libvirt-daemon`

Then I create my xml file with basics options

`virt-install --name toto --noautoconsole --print-xml --memory 4000 --import --disk=/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu20.04.qcow2,bus=sata --boot uefi --check all=off --graphics sdl > toto.xml`
Works fine, I get inside the xml
`<graphics type="sdl" display=":0" xauth="/home/user/.Xauthority"/>`

and then I try to create the VM

`virsh create toto.xml error: Failed to create domain from toto.xml error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2022-12-22T20:41:12.001933Z qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.` 
Any ideas?